# Cisco VPN cannot connect to server

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I followed this [link](http://www.humans-enabled.com/2011/06/how-to-connect-ubuntu-linux-to-cisco.html) to install and configure VPN for my pc. After that I connected to VPN and I saw the message: `VPN connection successfully established`. However, when I check my IP before and after connect to VPN it was the same. So can someone tell me how to fix this? I tried to search, reinstall openconnect but I still didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've created a private VPN on your local IP. You can use this VPN when you are at Starbucks or Mc Donald's and you won't have to worry as much about MITM attacks because you will be able to connect to your own private encrypted VPN linked to your home network IP.

If you want to use a public VPN in some other country or IP, I suggest using openvpn. To install run the following commands ain a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

To connect to a vpn, download an .ovpn file from a VPN provider such as [vpnate.net](http://www.vpngate.net/en/). Locate an "Open VPN Config File" and download this file (.ovpn). You can use TCP or UDP. UDP is faster but TCP is available for compatibility.

First download the .opvn file from this address:

http://www.vpngate.net/en/do_openvpn.aspx?fqdn=vpn956716021.opengw.net&ip=113.151.69.81&tcp=1703&udp=1468&sid=1416531490220&hid=558684

Then, run the following command to start the vpn:

```
sudo openvpn --config /path/to/file.opvn
```

Your IP should now be from Japan.

The basic command is

```
sudo openvpn --config
```

then, enter the path to the file or drag and drop the .ovpn file into the terminal, press enter and enter your password.

Another example with the file downloaded to your downloads folder:

```
sudo openvpn --config ~/Downloads/vpngate_vpn956716021.opengw.net_tcp_1703.ovpn
```

Some VPN servers will require a password and a username, however, VPNs on this website do not.

[The UDP version can be downloaded from here.](http://www.vpngate.net/en/do_openvpn.aspx?fqdn=&ip=182.168.127.178&tcp=443&udp=1194&sid=1416026411459&hid=6188)

[A world wide selection of "Open VPN Config Files" for free VPN servers can be found here.](http://www.vpngate.net/en/)